# Rendering in vue for loop from object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

I want to render question and answers and append one style to questions and other style to answers.

My data would look like this

```
 dialogTut:{
        mainTab:{
          q:"data with 42 people?",
          a:"hehe",
          q:"Are awesome people?",
          a:"sometimes",
          q:"Are awesome people2?",
        }

      },
```

And I want to render this in Label cause its nativescript (maybe is there other method )

```
<StackLayout class="dialog">

        <Label v-bind:key="item.index"
              :text="item" 
              :class="[item==q ? 'h3' : '' , 'a']" 
              v-for="item in mainTab">
        </Label>

        <Button class="drawer-close-button" text="Cancel" @tap="closeDialog"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
```

I tried some possibilities :class but do not work.
How to render this whole list and append 'h3' class to item.q and 'answer' class to item.a ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If there are duplicated keys in a JS object, only the last one is picked. You need an array to store them.
2. You can use object syntax to bind different class names: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax.

- 

```
dialogTut: {
  mainTab: [
    { type: "q", index: 1, content: "data with 42 people?" },
    { type: "a", index: 2, content: "hehe" },
    { type: "q", index: 3, content: "Are awesome people?" },
    { type: "a", index: 4, content: "sometimes" },
    { type: "q", index: 5, content: "Are awesome people2?" }
  ]
}

<StackLayout class="dialog">
  <Label :key="item.index"
         :text="item.content"
         :class="{'h3': item.type == 'q', 'answer': item.type == 'a'}"
         v-for="item in mainTab">
  </Label>
  <Button class="drawer-close-button" text="Cancel" @tap="closeDialog"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace to :class="[item==q ? 'h3' : 'answer']"
or :class="{ 'h3': item==q, 'answer': item==a }"

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure your data in this way:

```
mainTab:[
   {q:"data with 42 people?", a:"hehe"},
   {q:"Are awesome people?", a:"sometimes"}
]
```

and your html:

```
<template 
   :value="item.q" 
   v-for="(item,index) in mainTab">
   <p class="questionClass" :key="'q_'+index">{{item.q}}</p>
   <p class="answerClass" :key="'a_'+index">{{item.a}}</p>
</template>
```